# Unable to login to Minecraft java edition on Linux using Microsoft account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I have installed Minecraft java edition on latest linuxmint OS. I could see an option to login using email id and password. Which username and password is this ? I created a microsoft account. But I am unable to login with that. Do I need a mojang account for this ? Is it possible to create a new mojang account ?

Note : I haven't purchased the game yet. Wanted to try it out. Isn't that possible without purchase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't purchased the game yet and want to try, you don't need an account - neither Microsoft, nor Mojang one (the latter would be required to play Java Edition; the migration to Microsoft accounts haven't begun yet), but you can't play on the same binary as the full game - what you need is the [free trial](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/free-trial) version (scroll down for Java Edition). It has most of features of full game, but you can only play on a single world seed, and the world is reset after an hour of gameplay.